# Resume enumeration in sublist with enumitem package

Tags: enumitem

I want to mantain numeration in sublist (second order, Actions) between sections with enumitem package. With list of first order (Objectives) I got it, but I'm having trouble with sublists.

I've tried `resume` but it doesn't works in maintain enumeration. Under **Objective 3** must be **Action 5** (no Action 1 another time) and so on.

Look at my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Objective\ \theenumi\ }]
 \item Lorem
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Action\ \arabic*}] 
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{enumerate}
 \item Ipsum
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Action\ \arabic*},resume] 
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Objective\ \theenumi\ },resume]
 \item Lorem
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Action\ \arabic*},resume] 
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{enumerate}
 \item Ipsum
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Action\ \arabic*}] 
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What is the correct way of doing so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you can declare the sublist with a `series=<series name>`, which you can refer to in the later sublists with `resume=<series name>`. I wrapped the inner sublist with a custom environment so that there is less repetition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\newlist{innerenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist*[innerenumerate]{label=\textbf{Action\ \arabic*}, resume=inner}
\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Objective\ \theenumi\ }]
 \item Lorem
      \begin{innerenumerate}[series=inner]
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{innerenumerate}
 \item Ipsum
      \begin{innerenumerate}
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{innerenumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Objective\ \theenumi\ },resume]
 \item Lorem
      \begin{innerenumerate}
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{innerenumerate}
 \item Ipsum
      \begin{innerenumerate}
       \item ipsum
       \item dolorem
      \end{innerenumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works very well. Thanks for your help. I must practice a little more with enumitem because it's a powerful package and I use lists very often.

Comment: I would suggest to define a new list environment for the outer "objective" list as well. Having to type and read `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Objective\ \theenumi\ },resume]` is tedious. I'd also rename `innerenumerate` to `actionenum` or similar to make the macros more semantic.